# API Connection through node in React Form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

[image: Can't able to solve this error, tried with npm i but it's an error of file not found]
    const express = require('express');
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var cors = require('cors');

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



function getConnection() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        database: 'pms_tool'
    })
}



//DEL REQUEST
app.delete('/users/:kpiId', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Fetching user with kpiId: ' + req.params.kpiId);

    const connection = getConnection();

    const Id = req.params.kpiId;

    const queryString = 'DELETE FROM kpi_master WHERE kpiId = ?';
    connection.query(queryString, [Id], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to query for users: ' + err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        res.end('Record has been deleted!!!');
    });
});


//update kpi api 
app.put("/kpi_update/:kpiId", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.kpiId;
    const name = req.body.kpiName;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const queryString = " UPDATE kpi_master SET kpiName =  ? , description = ? WHERE kpiId = ? "
    getConnection().query(queryString, [name, description, id], (err, results, fields, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Not updated " + err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return
        }
        console.log('record updates ' + results.id)
        res.send(results)
    })

})


//create a new kpi
app.post('/user_create', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Trying to create a new user...');
    console.log('first name: ' + req.body.kpiName);
    const kpiName = req.body.kpiName;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const queryString = 'INSERT INTO kpi_master (kpiName,description) values(?,?)';
    getConnection().query(queryString, [kpiName, description], (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to insert new user :' + err);
            res.sendStatus(500);

            return;
        }
        console.log('Inserted a new user with id:', results.insertId);

        res.end();
    });
    res.end();
});




app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Responding to root route');
    res.send('Hello from ROOT');
});


//get kpi by single ID
app.get('/users/:kpiId', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Fetching user with kpiId: ' + req.params.kpiId);

    const connection = getConnection();

    const userId = req.params.kpiId;

    const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM kpi_master WHERE kpiId = ?';
    connection.query(queryString, [userId], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to query for users: ' + err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }

        console.log('I think we fetched users successfully');

        const users = rows.map((row) => {
            return { kpiName: row.kpiName, description: row.description };
        });

        res.json(users);
    });

    // res.end()
});


//get kpi
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM kpi_master';
    connection.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to query for users: ' + err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        res.json(rows);
    });
});


const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

It gives me the error as I've shared the image

[image: After installing mysql package i got this error and now the form is also not working][image: program runs succesfully but it'snot showing the data, as it is working in postman]I've made one datatable for listing records and on add we can add it through api. So now I've made api and add some records and made a file named server for api and it's working but i've called api in react form but can't able to list the api. As it shows this error...[image]

Comment: are you sure you have mysql module in your local.. check! mysql module is installed or not?

Comment: do `npm install mysql --save`

Comment: I have installed npm i mysql module still not working

Comment: Please add your code in text form, using code blocks instead of posting images. 
Then please edit your question to contain the actual error you're experiencing.

Comment: still it's not working as it shows that error I posted the screenshot too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your node_module for mysql is not installed in your node application. Kindly install it using

```
npm i mysql
```

and then restart your application again

Thank You.

Comment: installed mysql and also restarted it. Not working Still